# Accessing files over the network through a script running as NT Authority\System

Tags: powershell, csv, permissions, system, sccm

I'm not sure if I am asking this in the right spot or not, sorry if I am wrong.

I would like to know please, SCCM is currently operational in our school, and we use it to install software across our network.

I have a piece of software that requires a different channel for each room or staff laptop that it is installed in.

I have managed to set up a powershell script that polls a csv for the channel that should be assigned to each room, and when the script it run, it pulls that channel and installs the software with that channel assigned.

What I am having trouble with now, is that SCCM installs the software using the local system account, and the csv is located on a network share.
When the System account goes to poll the csv file it gets an access denied error, even though System has full control of the csv and directory that the csv is located in.

Is it just me not understanding the permissions that System has, or can System not interact with other devices over the network, I assumed that being system on both devices, it would be able to cross to another device and impersonate system on that device.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By simply adding Domain Computers to the files permissions list and assigning it Read/Write permissions, I am able to let any computer in this group (all computers on the domain) access the specific files.

This is also what Andy Arismendi was saying, however just an already setup group.

Answer (score 1):

The system account uses the machine account when accessing the network e.g. COMPNAME$, if you're on AD you can add a grant to that computer account to the file share ACL. If you don't have a domain you can create a local account with matching username and password on both machines and configure the service to run as that account.

Comment: This could be run from any computer though, as the software is advertised to the user, and the user can install it from any computer he or she is on, if I were to add 'everyone' with read/write access to the file alone, would that work, as I don't really care if someone were to access those files, we have backups of them, and there is nothing confidential in them.

Comment: @Random206 You could put their computer accounts in a group and put the group on the ACL.